# Java Spring handle string empty in SOAP response

Tags: java, spring, soap, jaxb

I using jaxb for soap service in Spring. And I have the field "name" which is value **empty string**("").
I found the response of api is

```
<name/>
```

but I want

```
<name></name>
```

I have definition of collection and test many case below but still not match.
Is it possible to configure JAXB or create some adapter to fix it.

```
@XmlElement(required = true, nillable = true)
protected String name;


@XmlElement()
protected String name;


@XmlElement(required = false)
protected String name;
```

Answer (score 0):

In XML `<name/>` and `<name></name>` are treated identically both meaning an empty element. Even if you manage to create the latter representation you'll have to tell the counterpart of your SOAP communication, that you give it a special meaning. This is not a good idea.

Maybe this will help you: When using JAXB for unmarshalling the pure existence of `<name/>` results in an empty string, whereas a missing element results in the string being null.